# Why am I getting a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException when I try to replace `\\` with `\`?

Tags: java, string

I have to replace `\\` with `\` in Java. The code I am using is

```
System.out.println( (MyConstants.LOCATION_PATH + File.separator + myObject.getStLocation() ).replaceAll("\\\\", "\\") );
```

But I don't know why it is throwing `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

It says `String index out of range: 1`

What could be the reason? I guess it is because the first argument `replaceAll` accepts a pattern. What could be the possible solution?

---

**Stacktrace**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:558)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:696)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Matcher.java:806)
    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2000)
```

---

**Answer Found**

[asalamon74](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21348/asalamon74) posted the code I required, but I don't know why he deleted it. In any case here it is.

There is a [bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6523151) already filed in Java's bug database. (Thanks for this reference, asalamon.)

```
yourString.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\");
```

Amazingly, both search and replace string are the same :) but still it does what I require.

Comment: Also, it should be File.separator isnt it?

Comment: What is the result of the concatenation of the various fields that you have ?

Comment: Based on your "answer found" I recommend you try: System.out.println( MyConstants.LOCATION_PATH + File.separator + myObject.getStLocation() ) and save yourself a few CPU cycles. :)

Comment: Regardless of managing to get it to work with replaceAll, I'd still recommend using replace unless you *really* want a regular expression.

Comment: That replaceAll() call is still wrong; there should be eight backslashes in the regex, not four.  But Jon's right, use the replace() method and save yourself the hassle.  Better still, forget about the file.separator property and just use forward slashes.

Comment: About that bug: yes, there's a bug *report*, but it was rejected. What you're seeing is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 17):

Use `String.replace` instead of `replaceAll` to avoid it using a regex:

```
String original = MyConstants.LOCATION_PATH + File.seperator 
    + myObject.getStLocation();
System.out.println(original.replace("\\\\", "\\"));
```

Personally I wouldn't do it this way though - I'd create MyConstants.LOCATION_PATH_FILE as a `File` and then you could write:

```
File location = new File(MyConstants.LOCATION_PATH_FILE,
                         myObject.getStLocation());
```

which will do the right thing automatically.

Comment: That was just an example. take this, i have to replace '\\' with '\' in the string "hello\\!!\is\\that\\\\you" !

Comment: The closer you can make your example to reality, the more likely you are to get helpful answers. However, the use of just "replace" should still work fine.

Answer (score 8):

Well, i tried

```
    String test = "just a \\ test with some \\\\ and others \\\\ or \\ so";
    String result = test.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\");
    System.out.println(test);
    System.out.println(result);
    System.out.println(test.equals(result));
```

and got, as expected

```
just a \ test with some \\ and others \\ or \ so
just a \ test with some \\ and others \\ or \ so
true
```

What you really *need* is

```
string.replaceAll("\\\\\\\\", "\\\\");
```

to get

```
just a \ test with some \\ and others \\ or \ so
just a \ test with some \ and others \ or \ so
false
```

You want to find: `\\`  (2 slashes)
which needs to be escaped in the regex: `\\\\`  (4 slashes)
and escaped in Java: `"\\\\\\\\"`  (8 slashes)
same for the replacement...

Answer (score 2):

For the regex, if you want to change `\` to `\\`, you should do this:

```
if (str.indexOf('\\') > -1)
    str = str.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");
str = "\"" + str + "\"";
```

Where `\\\\` means `\` and `\\\\\\\\` means `\\`.

Answer (score 1):

File.seperator is already escaped as is any string object so you are escaping them twice.

You only need to escape values that you are entering as a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
cadena.replaceAll("\\\\","\\\\\\\\")
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is :

```
str.replace(**'**\\**'**, **'**/**'**); //with char method not String
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that `replaceAll()` uses regexps and the backslash is an escape character in regexps as well as in Java - it might be necessary to double the number of backslashes.

In general you should always post the full stack trace of exceptions, it is much easier to diagnose the problem that way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need to do is:

```
System.out.println( (MyConstants.LOCATION_PATH + File.separator + myObject.getStLocation() ).replaceAll("\\\\\\\\", "\\\\") );
```

The regular expression String is actually four backslashes, which is a regular expression that matches two backslashes.

The replacement String has to be four slashes as per Java documentation, from:
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String)

> Note that backslashes () and dollar signs ($) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string. Dollar signs may be treated as references to captured subsequences as described above, and backslashes are used to escape literal characters in the replacement string.

Answer (score -2):

```
final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
final StringCharacterIterator iterator = new StringCharacterIterator(str);
char character =  iterator.current();
while (character != CharacterIterator.DONE )
{
  if (character == '\\\\') {
     result.append("\\");
  }
  else {
    result.append(character);
  }

  character = iterator.next();
}

System.out.print(result);
```

Comment: `if (character == '\\\\')` is a syntax error.  You're trying to squeeze two backslashes into one `char` literal.